# How do I check if the user is using the network time in Android?

Tags: android

how do I check if the user is using the network time or if he changed it himself?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, checking the following setting would help:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AUTO_TIME

You'll need two permissions: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS and android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for, you are a scholar and a gentleman